# How to load multiple assembies

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

1. In C# programming, I am trying to load multiple assemblies with same features in their namespaces, for reflection. For example, load all assemblies with the same prefix in namespaces
   ABC.*.*
   ABC.*
   ABC.***.***.***
   How to realize it?
2. Similar question is how to load multiple assemblies with same features in their names?

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: What do you mean by "load assemblies"? Do you mean loading it for reflection, importing it, referencing it in your project, etc..?

Comment: The assemblies are loaded for reflection.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "same features" ?

Comment: As I showed in the example, the assemblies with names which have common prefix: "Shape1.dll", "Shape231.dll" "Shape392.3eisl.exe", etc.

Comment: I saw it on another SO how to do this via reflection, but would loading the assemblies into their own appdomain work?  If you load them into the current appdomain, you cannot unload it until your program closes.  Multiple app-domains would allow loading multiple versions at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(filepath)`

Comment: The assemblies I am trying to load may in different folders. And under the same folder, there could be some extra assemblies which are not required.

Comment: Uh huh.  And thus..? so on, and so forth..? So what?

Comment: For a simple case, if I need to load multiple assemblies with same name prefix under the same folder, which function can make it work? I tried Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(filepath) but not successful.

Answer (score 0):

For question number 2 - if you have the files of these assemblies, you can use [Assembly.LoadFrom(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) or [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx) and pass the names of those files that match your desired pattern.